# How add to a backspace character to a string literal?

Tags: php, string

I use `\b` to generate backspace in PHP: But I think it doesn't work:

```
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
            $n = $_GET['n'];
            $c = $_GET['c'];
            $space = "&nbsp;"; $i=0; $j=0; $k=0;

            do{
                $space = $space."&nbsp;";
                $i++;
            }while($i < $n);

            for($j=0; $j < $n ; $j++){
                echo $space;

                for($k=0; $k < $j*2 - 1; $k++){
                    echo $c;
                }
                echo $space."\b";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?  The br suggests this data is going to a web browser, so newlines and backspace characters will be ignored for rendering?

Comment: @Jane T, newlines will not be ignored, they will be treated as spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to delete last char in a string just do:

```
$space = substr($space,0,-1);     //> Reccomanded
```

or

```
substr($space,0,count($space)-1); //> Slower
```

or

```
substr_replace($space,'',-1);     //> Uglier
```

Comment: Won't downvote you for it, but the unset method doesn't actually work. That would result in a "Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets". The substring way works though.

Comment: `unset()` does not work... Not on 5.3.5 (neither Windows nor Linux), and not on 5.2.17 (Windows).

Comment: Hm maybe some old php version did it because I remeber some years ago that code. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this: `"\x8"` ?

Comment: Doesn't `\x` have to be followed by **two** hex characters?

Comment: @binaryLV, I haven't tested, but documentation says `\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}`. So it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [it's not on the list](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double). You have to use the octal or hexadecimal notation.

In any case, the backspace character has little use outside a text console, not to mention HTML.

Comment: on text console it owns actually! you can simulate an "ajax" loading with it. (`| \b \ \ b / \b` )